# loading eulervm creates wrong symbols in \mathtt

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, eulervm

When I import eulervm this breaks some code in \mathtt. Symbols suddenly turn into other symbols. There is no problem in normal math-mode.

A small working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
This produces the wrong symbol:
\Huge
\[\mathtt{\sigma}\]
\normalsize
This is fine:
\Huge
\[\sigma\]
\end{document}
```

In the first case instead of σ I get œ. What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What would be the reason for `\mathtt{\sigma}`?

Comment: In the real use case σ is part of some program-code. \mathtt is used as a visual marker that this is source code.

Comment: You'll probably need to find a different forn for mathtt then, probably not many have greek letters in tt

Comment: @Rincewind You discovered that `$\mathtt{complicated formula}$` is bad and only the letters should be marked with `\mathttt`.

Comment: program code shouldn't be set in math.

Comment: I am using a version of λ-calculus where I need σ, have product types, function types and annotations using \top and \bot. Hence a significant part of my syntax are maths symbols which as far as I know I have to set in math-mode.

Comment: The `eulervm` package defines `\sigma` and the other Greek letters as `\mathalpha`, so they obey math font changing commands. This is because it wants to define `\mathbold`. If you don't need `\mathbold` you can redefine all Greek letters as `\mathord`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy lines 70 to 96 of `eulervm.sty` in your document preamble

```latex
     70 \DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"0B}
     71 \DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}   {\mathalpha}{letters}{"0C}
     72 \DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"0D}
     73 \DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"0E}
     74 \DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0F}
     75 \DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}   {\mathalpha}{letters}{"10}
     76 \DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}    {\mathalpha}{letters}{"11}
     77 \DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"12}
     78 \DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}   {\mathalpha}{letters}{"13}
     79 \DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"14}
     80 \DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda} {\mathalpha}{letters}{"15}
     81 \DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}     {\mathalpha}{letters}{"16}
     82 \DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}     {\mathalpha}{letters}{"17}
     83 \DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}     {\mathalpha}{letters}{"18}
     84 \DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}     {\mathalpha}{letters}{"19}
     85 \DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}    {\mathalpha}{letters}{"1A}
     86 \DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"1B}
     87 \DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}    {\mathalpha}{letters}{"1C}
     88 \DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"1D}
     89 \DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}    {\mathalpha}{letters}{"1E}
     90 \DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}    {\mathalpha}{letters}{"1F}
     91 \DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}    {\mathalpha}{letters}{"20}
     92 \DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"21}
     93 \DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"22}
     94 \DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"23}
     95 \DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}  {\mathalpha}{letters}{"24}
     96 \DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi} {\mathalpha}{letters}{"27}
```

(line numbers just for reference) and replace `\mathalpha` with `\mathord`.

*Caveat.* You'll lose the possibility of using `\mathbold` on lowercase Greek letters.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Would you mind explaining what is actually going on? What is the difference between \mathalpha and \mathord? Why does this difference only become relevant in \mathttt? Why does \mathord mean that \mathbold is no longer possible?

Comment: @Rincewind A character declared `\mathalpha` will respect the math font changes ordered by commands such as `\mathbf`, `\mathtt` and similar. This means that `\mathtt{\alpha}` will use the character in slot `"0B` of the font used by `\mathtt` (which is not an alpha, as you discovered). Characters declared `\mathord` don't obey such font change commands and are always typeset in the declared font (here `letters`). The `eulervm` command `\mathbold` is defined similarly to `\mathbf`: thus the need of declaring lowercase Greek letters with `\mathalpha`, so they change under `\mathbold`.

Answer (score 0):

In the modern toolchain, you can load `unicode-math` and set the math font (perhaps with a `range=` option) to Neo Euler.  This uses a single encoding, Unicode, and avoids the complexity of 7- and 8-bit legacy encodings entirely.